# How can i fix this Type Error that appears?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, typeerror

I'm new to python. For a project at school, I have to make a sort of card game.
here is the code that I use:

```
playersDeckSize = deckSize / 2
i = 0
for i in range(int(playersDeckSize)):
   playerDeck[i] = cards[random.randint(0, len(cards - 1))]

   computerDeck[i] = cards[random.randint(0, len(cards - 1))]
   i = i + 1
```

Comment: What is the full error you are getting?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: what is the deckside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in this expression:

```
len(cards - 1)
```

`cards` appears to be a list; you can't subtract `1` from a list.  I suspect that you mean

```
len(cards) - 1
```